# Why new ManagementObject(@"root\WMI", "BcdStore", null) throws exception?

Tags: c#, wmi

Using `WMI Code Creator`, I'm trying to issue a call to `root\WMI\BcdStore.EnumerateObjects()`. However I get an exception on the first line of code:

```
var classInstance = new ManagementObject(
    @"root\WMI", "BcdStore", null); // <== exception!!!

// Obtain in-parameters for the method
var inParams = classInstance.GetMethodParameters("EnumerateObjects");

// ...
```

The exception is:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Management.dll

Additional information: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of the [ManagementObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xa94e7c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor which you are using is expecting a WMI Path as parameter, and you are only passing the class name, so you must use some thing like this.

```
var classInstance = ManagementObject(@"root\WMI", "BcdStore.FilePath=''", null);
```

Note : The system store is denoted by an empty string ("").

Comment: It works, thanks! but how do you know that I need a constructor here? it doesn't appear in the documentation of [ManagementObject Constructor (String, String, ObjectGetOptions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xa94e7c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). in the documentation of [BcdStore class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says: `class BcdStore { string FilePath; };` this syntax is awkward - the brackets are curly, not square...