# C# WMI method IsActivated from Win32_Tpm class throws "Invalid method Parameter(s)"

Tags: c#, wmi

I am trying to run the [IsActivated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secprov/isactivated-win32-tpm), [IsEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secprov/isenabled-win32-tpm) and [IsOwned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secprov/isowned-win32-tpm) methods from the [Win32_Tpm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secprov/win32-tpm) WMI class in C#.

For testing purposes, I have created a console application with the following code:

```
        ManagementScope managementScope = new ManagementScope(@"ROOT\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftTpm");
        ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Tpm");
        ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass(managementScope, managementPath, null);

        managementClass.InvokeMethod("IsActivated", null);
```

InvokeMethod throws *"Invalid method Parameter(s)"*

The *IsActivated* method signature does not mention any input parameter:

```
uint32 IsActivated(
  [out] boolean IsActivated
);
```

To confirm this, I ran:

```
managementClass.GetMethodParameters("IsActivated");
```

Which returned:

```
System.Management.ManagementObject.GetMethodParameters returned null
```

Visual Studio is launched with run as Admin and the app.manifest was configured to require Administrator privileges:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

The methods should definitely work, as showcased in [WMI Explorer](https://github.com/vinaypamnani/wmie2), but I am struggling to understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as an answer as I figured it out in the end and it could come in handy for those encountering the same struggles in the future.

To be able to run the InvokeMethod method, I needed to define a ManagementObject for the Win32_TPM WMI Instance and not a ManagementClass.

The key on how to define that instance came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012756/11828837) in another thread for a similar question and this [C#Corner article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/an-in-depth-look-at-wmi-and-instrumentation-part-ii/).

To define the instance, I needed 2 things:

- the path = "ROOT\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftTpm"
- the instance name = "Win32_Tpm=@"

I used the aforementioned WMI Explorer to figure out the instance name.

```
ManagementObject managementObject = new ManagementObject(@"ROOT\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftTpm", "Win32_Tpm=@", null);
```

Next I stored the output of the InvokeMethod in a ManagementBaseObject:

```
ManagementBaseObject OutParams = managementObject.InvokeMethod("IsActivated", null, null);
```

And finally, you can either parse all the PropertyData:

```
foreach(PropertyData propertyData in OutParams.Properties)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{propertyData.Name} = {propertyData.Value}");
}
```

To produce this output:

> IsActivated = True
>
> ReturnValue = 0

Or you can go straight for the PropertyValue:

```
Console.WriteLine($"IsActivated = {OutParams.GetPropertyValue("IsActivated")}");
```

> IsActivated = True